# How to upgrade MYSQL 5.0.82sp1 and Phpmyadmin 2.8.2.4 in Centos 5?

Tags: mysql, centos

I need update to a new and stable version.  i´m search but not have good lucky.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the core centos repo don't have want your looking for (and neither does the testing repo), try these:

- [Atomic Turtle](http://www.atomicrocketturtle.com/Joomla/)
- [RPM Forge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge)
- [PBONE](http://rpm.pbone.net/)

Comment: thx work fine but how upgrade to any version if want?

Comment: @Seeal - if you want to use any version you want, you will have to compile from source. Pre-packaged versions intergrate with your exisiting system better, and make sure you have all the dependencies installed, however depend on people (re)creating them when an update upstream comes out.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use CentOS's package manger 'yum' for MySQL:

```
yum update mysql-server
```

For phpMyAdmin, just download the latest stable version from their website http://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and copy that to the desired location. Don't forget to alter the config.inc.php file to your wishes afterwards.

Comment: Setting up Update Process
Could not find update match for mysql-server
No Packages marked for Update

this error launch :(

Comment: I doubt your comment phpmyadmin the fixed mysql but not yet, thank you very much for the help